# LDAP - LDIF file? - Complete Confusion

Tags: ldap, freebsd, openldap, ldif

Can someone please explain what the LDIF file on openldap is used for? Is this how you set the schema of the database? Or is this how you enter in users in your database? What do I actually have below?

```html
dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: uid=tuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: person
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: top
uidNumber: 10000
gidNumber: 10000
homeDirectory: /home/tuser
loginShell: /bin/csh
uid: tuser
cn: tuser

dn: ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: cn=tuser,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
gidNumber: 10000
cn: tuser
```

Answer (score 1):

LDIF stands for LDAP Data Interchange Format, and represents a textual way to enter data or export data from an LDAP directory server. In the case, above, this represents a directory structure for users and groups under a "dc=example,dc=com" domain.

This data must obey to an LDAP schema which may or may not be already defined in your server (should be already there by default in OpenLDAP).